# Plone 4 : How to customize a method in Archetypes content types?

Tags: adapter, plone, archetypes, plone-4.x

I have tried, under Plone 4.3.3, to customize a class method of an archetype content type in one of my products.

I have a product `bsw.produit_1` with a content type `MyContent` defined as follows:

```
class MyContent(base.ATCTContent):

    implements(IMyContent)

    meta_type = "MyContent"
    schema = MyContent`

    def ma_fonction(self):

        ......
        return res
```

I want to modify the code of my function `ma_fonction` in another product. I have tried using an adapter and following the plone docs, but without success.

The class where I wish to customize the function:

```
class CustomClass(object):
    """  """

    implements(IMyContent)
    adapts(IMyContent)

    def at_post_payment_script(self, obj_transaction):
        """ """

            ......
            # My new code
            return res
```

The `configure.zcml` where I declared my adapter:

```
  <adapter for="bsw.produit_1.content.mycontent.MyContent"
           provides="bsw.produit_1.interfaces.IMyContent"
           factory=".customclass.CustomClass" />
```

In my zcml declaration, I've also tried putting `archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender` as `provides` or putting the interface `IMyContent` for `for` instead of the class.

None of these worked, every time, the customized code is not executed. Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: I've tried to the best of my abilities to translate into english, which I guess is one of the reasons your question was marked as "unclear what you're asking". Feel free to improve my translation, I hope I've rendered your intent correctly.

Comment: I don't get what you mean when you say "The class where I wish to customize the function:...". Isn't your scope to simply override the original method `MyContent.ma_fonction` ?

Comment: @keul: it was "customizer" in the original, I should probably have rendered that as "change". I'm not sure why there's two different method names in the snippets, though, maybe Sebastien can help us there.

Comment: @keul:`ma_fonction` is an archetype method, in the plone documentation its say to use adapter for override archetype method.
Do you know an other method to override an archetype method ?

Comment: @Sebastien I think you misunderstood something in the documentation.

Comment: @keul: I can override my method but the new code will be applied in every plone site on my instance if my product is in my buildout. I want apply my custom code only if my product is install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you need depends on what you want to achieve.

But archetypes.schemaextender is the wrong solution.
schemaextender is there to modify the schema, this includes:

- fields order
- field/widget attributes
- schemata
- setter/getter of a field
- new fields
- override fields

To implement your own adaptera is definitely the right approach.

First you need to implement a adapter for the default behavior.
Second, you need to adapt the context and the request. The request is important, since that's a way to define a more specific adapter if your `other` product is installed.

Python code for the default implementation (adapter.py):

```python
from zope.component import adapts
from zope.interface import Interface
from zope.interface import implements


class IBehavior(Interface):
    def __init__(context, request)
        """Adapts context and request"""

    # ... more ...


class DefaultBehavior(object):
    implements(IBehavior)
    adapts(IMyContent, Interface)  # IMPORTAN two discriminators 

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    def __call__(self):

        # your default implementation goes here.
```

Register the adapter with zcml:

```xml
<adapter factory=".adapter.DefaultBehavior" />
```

Your now able to call the default adapter in `ma_fonction`

```python
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter


class MyContent(base.ATCTContent)

    def ma_fonction(self):
        adapter = getMultiAdapter((self, self.REQUEST), IDefaultBehavior)
        return adapter()
```

Now you can implement a more specific adapter in your `other` product using a browserlayer. Check documentation,  [how to register a browserlayer](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/layers.html)

In your `other`package you can now register a adapter which implements the same `IBehavior` interface, but also adapts your browserlayer.

```python
from other.package.interfaces import IOtherPackageLayer
from zope.component import adapts
from zope.interface import implements


class DifferenBehavior(object):
    implements(IBehavior)
    adapts(IMyContent, IOtherPackageLayer)  # IMPORTAN adapt the browserlayer not Interface 

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    def __call__(self):

        # your different implementation goes here.
```

Register also with zcml:

```xml
<adapter factory=".adapter.DifferenBehavior" />
```

Your `ma_fonction`now calls the default adapter, if the `other` package is not installed. And the different adapter if the `other` package is installed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method you can use (although not politically correct!) is *monkey-patching*.

Take a look at [collective.monkeypatcher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.monkeypatcher), you simply need a configuration like that (in your 3rd party product):

```
<monkey:patch
    description=""
    class="your.package.MyContent"
    original="ma_fonction"
    replacement=".monkeys.new_ma_fonction"
    />
```

Then in your package create also a `monkeys.py` module with the new method inside:

```
def new_ma_fonction(self):
    # do stuff
    return res
```

Comment: I try also with collective.monkeypatcher but my custom code is apply in every plone site on my instance.
I want apply my custom code only if my product is install

Comment: So you can act that way: your product can register a Plone browserlayer (http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/layers.html#add-on-layer-for-clean-extensions) and in the `new_ma_fonction` you can check if the current request provides the interface:

if MyBrowserLayerInterface.providedBy(self.REQUEST): ...